# Django Admin - Change Model Page - URLs with UUID instead of ID

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I have a `BaseModel` class that all my models inherit with a `uuid` like so:

```py
class BaseModel(models.Model):

    ''' Extension of base model class '''
    
    uuid = models.UUIDField(unique=True, default=uuid4, editable=False)
    ...
```

How can I change the django admin behavior such that I can access the change page for an instance using the object UUID instead of the ID?

Presently:
`.../admin/my_app/my_model/7/change/`

Preferred:
`.../admin/my_app/my_model/b6a98f1d-6b26-4399-8d68-62ec1ce12c41/change/`

Comment: The primary key field is the one used in the urls, is changing the PK of all your models to the uuid field an option?

Comment: yes that perhaps is a better option

Comment: Is you application deployed with production data? If you could drop and recreate your database again with the new PK then the transition might be simple, if you have to migrate existing data with foreign keys to the old id then it may be complex

Comment: I can take care of the data migration - a good solution assuming no problems with data would be great

Comment: Adding `primary_key=True` to the `uuid` field then recreating all your migrations and DB is the simplest solution if you don't need to keep data. If you need to keep data then the solution becomes too complex for an answer

Comment: After doing some research - it appears it is best to leave the `pk` as an integer, and use the `uuid` as a secondary id field. That being the case, is there anyway to achieve what I am requesting above?

Comment: Do you mean, is there any way to use the uuid in the admin URL instead of the primary key?

Comment: Yes - this is the question I am asking

Comment: No, it's not currently possible to use anything other than the PK in the admin url unfortunately

Comment: is there anyway to "capture" the uuid and convert it to an ID?

Answer (score 0):

I've managed this solution without having to set the `UUID` as the primary key:

```py
from django.contrib import admin


class BaseModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    """ base model admin with custom behavior """

    def get_object(self, request, object_id, from_field=None):
        """ get object based on uuid insead of id """

        # get queryset, model, field:
        queryset = self.get_queryset(request)
        model = queryset.model
        field = model._meta.get_field('uuid') if from_field is None else model._meta.get_field(from_field)
        
        # try to return instance:
        try:
            object_id = field.to_python(object_id)
            return queryset.get(**{field.name: object_id})
        except:
            return None
```